# SQL Left-Join Statement for cart

Tags: sql, join, left-join

Can someone explain this sql code for me we use it to add items on cart

```
SELECT 
  c.crt_id, 
  i.item_id, 
  i.item_name, 
  i.price,i.image 
FROM 
  cart c 
  LEFT JOIN item i ON c.item_id = i.item_id 
WHERE 
  c.customer_no = 1 
AND 
  c.delete_flg = 0
```

Comment: This code only selects data from the data.  It does not modify any data, so I don't see how it "adds items to a cart".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  SELECT 
   c.crt_id,
   i.item_id,
   i.item_name,
   i.price,
   i.image 
  FROM cart c 
  LEFT JOIN item i ON c.item_id = i.item_id -- return all items from cart regardless of if the customer has an order or not
  WHERE c.customer_no = 1 -- only fetches data for customer no 1
  AND     c.delete_flg = 0     -- as long as the there is no items in cart that is deleted
```

So, return all items from cart regardless of whether the customer has an order or not and he has not removed any items from the cart for customer no 1.

Answer (score 0):

`cart c LEFT JOIN item i` retrieves all the carts with their items, related to the `WHERE c.customer_no = 1 AND c.delete_flg = 0` clause.

The `LEFT JOIN` implies a cart is retrieved whether it has items or not. A simple `JOIN` (equals to `INNER JOIN`) would have made only the carts with at least 1 item to be retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

1. It takes all elements in table cart and sees if, for each one there is a matching result in table item joining both tables by item_id. If there are matching entries, it will return all combinations. If there are not, it will return the entry from table cart and null as a result from table item.
2. Filters the previous results by customer_no (of table cart) being 1 and delete_flag (of table cart) being 0.
3. It just returns the columns included between the select and the from statements.

Answer (score 0):

This statement:

```
SELECT c.crt_id, i.item_id, i.item_name, i.price, i.image
FROM cart c LEFT JOIN
     item i
     ON c.item_id = i.item_id
WHERE c.customer_no = 1 AND c.delete_flg = 0;
```

returns all items for all non-deleted carts for customer `1`.  If cart has an item that is not in the `item` table, then a row is still returned, but all but the first column are `NULL`.

It does not modify any data in the database, because it is a `SELECT` query.  If it does anything to carts, then that is subsequent code that uses `UPDATE`/`INSERT`/`DELETE` (or something similar) on the results returned by the query.